# Replace a shower handle and faucet, new configuration

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet, bathtub

I currently have a handle for hot/cold, and part of that fixture there's a toggle switch to flip from shower to faucet. The the spout is just a spout. I'd like to replace it with a new configuration where the hot/cold handle just does that, and then the spout itself has the toggle for the shower/faucet by pulling up/down.

Will I have any issues with a simple swap? Do I need to replace with a handle that functions the same way this one does? Appreciate the help!
[image: faucet handle]

Comment: what does this mean? ... `replace it with a new configuration`

Comment: @jsotola I mean replacing the current setup where you flip from shower to faucet via the handle, to a new setup where the flip from shower to faucet is on the spout instead of the handle.

Comment: After more research looks like the question is if I can have the diverter moved to my spout, when it's currently on my hot/cold water handle

Comment: You want to replace the shower valve with one that doesn’t have a diverter, and instead uses a diverter/block on the spout, correct? What is your access to the valve? Do you need to replace from the tile side, or is the other side of the wall just drywall?

Comment: Thanks @TimB I only have access from the tile side. And yes, your explanation is is ideally what I'd like to do, but I'd it requires significant plumbing or opening walls I'll just replace like for like.

Answer (score 1):

The diverter just blocks the pipe going to the tub spout, diverting the water flow to the shower. You can add a spout with a diverter and just ignore the existing diverter.

Comment: There _might_ be a _bit_ of extra difficulty getting the old diverter rod from the handle to the tub spout out of the wall, depending on what access to the other side is like, but this is spot on info.

Comment: Thanks for the response @vredesbyrd although my hope is to replace all of the fixtures, both the handle and the spout. Is it as easy as just replacing the 2 existing fixtures or is their plumbing associated with the diverter location? Thank you

Comment: @Soler There is going to be some plumbing work when replacing the shower valve no matter what you do. If you just want to replace the trim (handle, cover plate, and spout) then it would be easy. Delta still sells the same style shower kit, but I don't know if it would be compatible. You could remove the handle and cover plate and then post a picture of what you have in the wall and the community may be able to give more advice.

Comment: Thanks Vredesbyrd, I think I'll swap like for like!